# Finding A Sub Element Of A Selenium Web Object In Python

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to find a sub element of an already found web object element.

For example I have this website

```
<div id="bar">
    <span>name</span>
    <a>two</a>
    <li>three</li>
</div>
```

and this python code

```
element = driver.find_element_by_id('bar')
```

I would like to then take this element here and refine it so that I can better filter out results. Something where i can break this one variable into further variables to perform if statements on.

example

```
name = span section
link = href link
ul = list
```

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `find_element` for your already found web element:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_id('bar')

name = element.find_element_by_tag_name('span').text
link = element.find_element_by_tag_name('a').get_attribute('href')
ul = element.find_elements_by_css_selector('ul li')
```

Comment: It will be a good idea to name the var as `bar_element`... that way the code is understandable...